# Module Error for "from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier"

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

When I try to run the following commands, I get a module error. I am not sure what is wrong.

```
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[10], line 1
----> 1 from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.wrappers'

from tensorflow.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[11], line 1
----> 1 from tensorflow.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.keras.wrappers'
```

I did try to uninstall all the library and also anaconda and again installed everything. Getting the same error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Keras, scikit, and tensorflow can be tricky. I recommend using SciKeras which is derived from `tensorflow.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn`, especially because the original TensorFlow wrappers are not actively maintained and are due for removal in the next release.

Install like so:

```
pip install scikeras[tensorflow]      # gpu compute platform
pip install scikeras[tensorflow-cpu]  # cpu
```

Change import statement (-) --> (+). The following executed for me:

```
- from tensorflow.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
+ from scikeras.wrappers import KerasClassifier
```

I know you said anaconda... I used to use conda but do not currently have it installed on my system so I cannot 100% confirm conda install will behave identically. Either way, make sure you are consistent with your package managers and install after activating your virtual environments.

Here is the documentation for SciKeras:

https://adriangb.com/scikeras/stable/migration.html#why-switch-to-scikeras